# Prometheus failes to reconnect docker daemon on localhost

Tags: docker, prometheus

As I am new to monitoring with prometheus I have installed grafana and prometheus with docker compose on the machine I used for testing and it worked to have the IP of the Host in the prometheus.yml

Now after docker compose down docker compose up the connection is refused.

prometheus.yml has

```
- job_name: 'docker'
  static_configs:
    - targets: ['host.docker.internal:9323']
```

Docker daemon.json has

```
"metrics-addr" : "127.0.0.1:9323"
```

and

```
curl http://localhost:9323/metrics
```

works fine from the console but in Prometheus shows this error.

```
Get "http://host.docker.internal:9323/metrics": dial tcp: lookup host.docker.internal on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host
```

How would I corretly connect prometheus from inside a docker container to the docker daemon on the host ?

Comment: Can you show the full connection refusal you get?
And while it's probably a silly question, did compose and the regular command you ran both ran as the same user? This could be a user/group permission issue.

Comment: @Uberhumus  added the error message to the question. Yes same console where I run docker compose up -d and the curle command

Comment: Were there any changes done between the `docker compose down` and the `docker compose up`? Also, could it be that the original time you ran compose you ran it as root?

Comment: In what network are the containers? This can be found using the `docker inspect` command.

Comment: that was it,. Changing back prometheus.yml back to the NDS Name of the host and for now the metrics setting in daemon.json to unstrestricted it works again. Thanks @Uberhumus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you experienced seems to be related to network configuration and potential permissions settings within your Docker environment. The solution can be derived from the comments and consists of the following steps:

1. Modify the `prometheus.yml` configuration file. Replace the `host.docker.internal` target under the static_configs section with the DNS name of your host machine. The `host.docker.internal` hostname might not be resolving correctly, hence the need to use the actual DNS name of your host.
2. Adjust the metrics settings in the `daemon.json` file to be
   unrestricted. This setting might be necessary to bypass potential
   permission-related issues that might be preventing Prometheus from
   accessing the Docker daemon metrics.

After performing these changes, ensure your monitoring setup is functioning as expected. If you encounter further issues, additional debugging steps include inspecting the network your containers are operating in using the `docker inspect` command and verifying the user executing the docker commands to avoid potential permission-related issues.